# Asymmetrical Layout in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

Is it possible to create asymmetrical layouts (as opposed to square layouts) in Java Swing ? I'm thinking of something like this:

[image: AsymmetricalLayout]

Is this achievable with any layout manager ? If not, I'd be interested in an explanation, too.

Comment: Yes, `GridBagLayout` would be the starting point, but I'd also consider using compound layouts to achieve a finer level of control

Comment: If you think about a window with a non-rectangular shape, then you in for a world of fun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, the long answer is some what more complicated.

To start with, I'd be using `GridBagLayout` as my primary choice of layout manager, but I might consider `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout` as additional options.  The point is, you want to break down your layout into manageable chunks of functionality and figure out the best solution to solve it's particular problems.  You then want to piece together these individual elements back into a large picture, using the layout managers most appropriate to solve the problem each piece presents.

I'd just like to say that your basic layout screams `JTable` to me.

[image: GridBagLayout]

If, however, you're interested in a non-rectangular window, then it becomes somewhat more difficult, mostly because Java doesn't support decorated transparent windows (ie, windows with native frames)

> If not, I'd be interested in an explanation, too

Okay, this is some what more complicated, but, it basically comes down to the fact that everything painted on the screen is contained in a, rectangular bounding box.  This box was filled with a background color and the content was painted onto it.

This was done for efficiency, because everything behind this bounding box doesn't need to be painted.

As hardware became faster and rendering pipelines took more advantage of higher end libraries, like DirectX and OpenGL, it became possible to start dealing with opacity across a broader spectrum of the system, such as individual windows.

So, even when you see that really cool, curvy, funky looking UI, it's contained within a rectangular bounding box, which is transparent :/

This is pretty basic graphics concepts.  Remember, it's much easier and faster to calculate a rectangular bound box (intersections/hit detection/etc) then a non-rectangular one

[image: Transparent Window]

Per-pixel alpha is actually rather intensive to perform, which is another reason it wasn't original used at a OS/every day level, the system resources could be better used for other things

## Runnable Example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 0.5;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            add(new FieldsPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 20)), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class FieldsPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel fields;
        private JLabel filler;

        public FieldsPane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
            fields = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            filler = new JLabel();
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            fields.add(filler, gbc);

            addFields(new JLabel("Col1"), new JLabel("Col2"), new JLabel("Col3  "));
            addFields(new JTextField(10), new JTextField(10), new JTextField(10));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(fields, gbc);

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");
            buttons.add(add);
            buttons.add(remove);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(buttons, gbc);
        }

        protected void addFields(JComponent col1, JComponent col2, JComponent col3) {
            GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout) fields.getLayout();
            GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints(filler);
            fields.add(makeRow(col1, col2, col3), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            layout.setConstraints(filler, gbc);
        }

        protected JPanel makeRow(JComponent col1, JComponent col2, JComponent col3) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 0.33;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            panel.add(col1, gbc);
            panel.add(col2, gbc);
            panel.add(col3, gbc);
            return panel;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks ! I have no experience in graphics programming so far, so I didn't know that even those "really cool, curvy, funky looking UI" as you put it brilliantly, are part of rectangular boxes. But come to think of it, of course this is way easier from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: Goes a long way back to even dos and text based solutions, but remember reading something when I was learning to code in Windows 3, about all controls been rectangular, regardless of the shapes they paint